# Update xml namespaces with data from a PHP form

Tags: php, xml

In the example below, the PHP form updates the XML with the text entered in the fields.

XML file labela.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inventors>
   <person>
      <name>change1</name>
      <comment>change2</comment>
   </person>
</inventors>
```

The PHP form used to change the "change1" and "change2" in the XML file

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <?php
 $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
 $xml->formatOutput = true;
 $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
 $xml->load("labela.xml");

 //Get item Element
 $element = $xml->getElementsByTagName("person")->item(0);

 //Load child elements
 $name = $element->getElementsByTagName("name")->item(0);
 $comment = $element->getElementsByTagName("comment")->item(0);

 //Replace old elements with new
 $element->replaceChild($name, $name);
 $element->replaceChild($comment, $comment);
 ?>

<?php if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name->nodeValue = $_POST["namanya"];
    $comment->nodeValue = $_POST["commentnya"];
    htmlentities($xml->save("labela.xml"));
} ?>

<form method="POST" action=''>
name <input type="text-name" value="<?php echo $name->nodeValue; ?>" name="namanya" />
comment  <input type="text-comment" value="<?php echo $comment->nodeValue; ?>"  name="commentnya"/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

How do I extract and update the strings change1 and change2 from the XML structure below, using PHP?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pt:document xmlns:pt="http://schemas.brother.info/ptouch/2007/lbx/main" xmlns:barcode="http://schemas.brother.info/ptouch/2007/lbx/barcode" xmlns:style="http://schemas.brother.info/ptouch/2007/lbx/style" xmlns:text="http://schemas.brother.info/ptouch/2007/lbx/text">
   <pt:body currentSheet="Folha 1">
      <style:sheet name="Folha 1">
         <pt:objects>
            <barcode:barcode>
               <barcode:qrcodeStyle model="2" eccLevel="15%" />
               <pt:data>change1</pt:data>
            </barcode:barcode>
            <text:text>
               <text:textStyle vertical="false" />
               <pt:data>change2</pt:data>
               <text:stringItem charLen="7">
                  <text:ptFontInfo>
                     <text:logFont name="Arial" />
                  </text:ptFontInfo>
               </text:stringItem>
            </text:text>
            <text:text>
               <text:textStyle vertical="false" />
               <pt:data>change3</pt:data>
            </text:text>
         </pt:objects>
      </style:sheet>
   </pt:body>
</pt:document>
```

thanks in advance to everyone who takes their time to help

Comment: I think you've provided too much background on *your task*, and not enough detail on *the specific problem you want help with*. Is the question actually "how do I extract the strings change1 and change2 from this XML structure?" What you do with them *after* your extract them is irrelevant - a large part of programming is breaking down a complex task into lots of small pieces.

Comment: If that *is* the question, I would suggest the very first thing you do is "pretty-print" your XML, formatting it so that it's indented based on its structure. That will give you a clearer idea of what elements you need to access. After that, you need to clarify what you are struggling with, since your first PHP example seems to show you know how to use DOM functions.

Comment: IMSoP, thanks for the quick reply. I rephrased the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal is to extract data from your XML using XPath.
You will get what you want by proceeding as follows:

load.php

```
<?php
$change1 = $_POST['change1'];
$change2 = $_POST['change2'];
$change3 = $_POST['change3'];   
$xml = simplexml_load_file('your_complex_xml.xml');
$xml->xpath('//pt:data')[0][0] = $change1;
$xml->xpath('//pt:data')[1][0] = $change2;
$xml->xpath('//pt:data')[2][0] = $change3;
$xml->asXML('new_complex_xml.xml');
```

form.php

```html
    <form method="post" action="load.php">
    <label for="change1">change1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="change1" id="change1"><br>
    <label for="change2">change2:</label>
    <input type="text" name="change2" id="change2"><br>
    <label for="change3">change3:</label>
    <input type="text" name="change3" id="change3"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Generate New XML">
    </form>
```

If you still can't, tell me which part you're having trouble with.
I wish you success in your projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's needed to translate the XML structure into an object

```
$xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
```

And then you can get access to the property.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I rephrased the question for clarity